# "In what forms of training do you participate in/to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> In what forms of training do you participate [in/to]?

Should I end that sentence with "in" or "to"? If I add "in" at the end, should I cut the "in" at the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

Better to keep it at the beginning and forget about it at the end. People will argue with this, but I still think it sounds better not to end a sentence on a preposition if it can be avoided.

Comment: Do you mean it should be "in what forms of training do you participate"?

Comment: @Alexander Troup   Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

It is to participate in sth. But when you begin a question with "In what forms of training do you participate? - then your sentence is complete. A further preposition at the end of the sentence is simply wrong.

Comment: Just so.  A further preposition at the end of a sentence is an aberration up with which we will not put.  :)

Comment: @Bob: Did you mean "an aberration up with which we will not put up"? :-)

Comment: Nope, don't believe so. That would suggest the alternative "an aberration we will not put up up with."

Comment: This reminds me of the humorous caveat, 'Never use a preposition to end a sentence with.' But, seriously, don't end a sentence with a preposition if you can reword the sentence smoothly, using another syntax.